# JS Async Directory Listing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am attempting to loop through an array containing directories and then return a combined array of all the items regardless of the number of directories. I was attempting to use the fs.readdir function to read the directories, but seeing as the fs.readdir function is an async function I can't pass the information back out of it.

Is there a way to use this function, but also make an array of the directory listings?

This is what I would like to do, but I know that this is just wrong. Hoping for a little guidance. I can provide any additional info. Thank you.

```
var docs = [];
libs.forEach(function(lib){
    fs.readdir(lib, function(err, files){
        files.forEach(function(file){
            docs.push(file);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can [learn async programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) or you can use [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

Comment: I am attempting to learn Async, but it is taking some time to wrap my head around. I thought about using the sync version, but I don't want to tie up the app while this function runs.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, then use the async answer in the linked comment.

Comment: I will look into it further. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Keep in mind that node ships with a [promise based fs api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_ordering_of_callback_and_promise_based_operations). Most async examples you'll find use promises/async-await so using the `fs/promises` will probably be easier to compare to similar code snippets

Comment: @JohnMoran My answer doesn't work, sorry and thanks for your time. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An async version:

```
const fs = require("fs/promises");

function listDirectories(dirs) {
  return Promise.all(dirs.map(dir => fs.readdir(dir))).then(files => files.flat());
}
```

It maps an array of strings (directories) into an array of promises returned by `fs.readdir`, followed by flattening the results of those promises once they resolve using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Flattening is required to transform this:

`[ [ "file1" ], [ "file2", "file3" ] ]` into `[ "file1", "file2", "file3" ]`.

Then, from an `async` function you can call it like so:

```
(async () => {
  const dirs = ["one", "two", "three"];
  try {
    let files = await listDirectories(dirs);
    console.log(files);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

Note that the above is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that you can use to test the function without having to integrate it into your codebase first.

Comment: This looks promising. I will have to give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Your assistance here basically unlocked the rest of the function I was working on. Thank you. I am not an experienced programmer, but I am trying to learn, and I have literally been stuck in this Hell for two days. Helped to clarify some async principles for me as well.

Comment: @JohnMoran Glad I could help, keep at it!